# Database Error - ORA-00904: "UM_MAPPED_ATTRIBUTE_DOMAIN": invalid identifier

Tags: wso2

We are trying to deploy WSO2 GREG 4.6 on Oracle RAC Database. As mentioned in instructions we ran the oracle_rac.sql dbscript to create the schema, but when we are trying to start the application, it fails with multiple database errors

[2014-03-11 21:42:58,366] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.util.DatabaseUtil} -  Database Error - ORA-00904: "UM_MAPPED_ATTRIBUTE_DOMAIN": invalid identifier

java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00904: "UM_MAPPED_ATTRIBUTE_DOMAIN": invalid identifier

```
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:447)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:396)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:951)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:513)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:227)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:531)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:208)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForRows(T4CPreparedStatement.java:1046)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1336)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3613)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeUpdate(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3694)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.executeUpdate(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1354)
at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.claim.dao.ClaimDAO.addClaimMapping(ClaimDAO.java:227)
at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.claim.dao.ClaimDAO.addCliamMappings(ClaimDAO.java:140)
at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm.populateProfileAndClaimMaps(DefaultRealm.java:420)
at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm.init(DefaultRealm.java:101)
at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealmService.initializeRealm(DefaultRealmService.java:223)
at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealmService.<init>(DefaultRealmService.java:101)
at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealmService.<init>(DefaultRealmService.java:114)
at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.internal.Activator.startDeploy(Activator.java:70)
at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.internal.BundleCheckActivator.start(BundleCheckActivator.java:61)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl$1.run(BundleContextImpl.java:711)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:702)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:683)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:381)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.resume(AbstractBundle.java:390)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.resumeBundle(Framework.java:1176)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:559)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:544)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.incFWSL(StartLevelManager.java:457)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.doSetStartLevel(StartLevelManager.java:243)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:438)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:1)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)
```

[2014-03-11 21:42:58,373] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealmService} -  Cannot initialize the realm.
org.wso2.carbon.user.core.UserStoreException: Database Error - ORA-00904: "UM_MAPPED_ATTRIBUTE_DOMAIN": invalid identifier

```
at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.claim.dao.ClaimDAO.addClaimMapping(ClaimDAO.java:261)
at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.claim.dao.ClaimDAO.addCliamMappings(ClaimDAO.java:140)
at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm.populateProfileAndClaimMaps(DefaultRealm.java:420)
at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm.init(DefaultRealm.java:103)
at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealmService.initializeRealm(DefaultRealmService.java:223)
at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealmService.<init>(DefaultRealmService.java:101)
at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealmService.<init>(DefaultRealmService.java:115)
at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.internal.Activator.startDeploy(Activator.java:71)
at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.internal.BundleCheckActivator.start(BundleCheckActivator.java:61)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl$1.run(BundleContextImpl.java:711)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:702)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:683)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:381)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.resume(AbstractBundle.java:390)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.resumeBundle(Framework.java:1176)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:559)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:545)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.incFWSL(StartLevelManager.java:458)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.doSetStartLevel(StartLevelManager.java:243)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:438)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:1)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)
```

Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00904: "UM_MAPPED_ATTRIBUTE_DOMAIN": invalid identifier

```
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:447)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:396)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:951)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:513)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:227)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:531)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:208)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForRows(T4CPreparedStatement.java:1046)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1336)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3613)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeUpdate(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3694)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.executeUpdate(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1354)
at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.claim.dao.ClaimDAO.addClaimMapping(ClaimDAO.java:227)
at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.claim.dao.ClaimDAO.addCliamMappings(ClaimDAO.java:140)
at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm.populateProfileAndClaimMaps(DefaultRealm.java:420)
at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm.init(DefaultRealm.java:101)
at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealmService.initializeRealm(DefaultRealmService.java:223)
at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealmService.<init>(DefaultRealmService.java:101)
at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealmService.<init>(DefaultRealmService.java:114)
at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.internal.Activator.startDeploy(Activator.java:70)
at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.internal.BundleCheckActivator.start(BundleCheckActivator.java:61)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl$1.run(BundleContextImpl.java:711)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:702)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:683)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:381)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.resume(AbstractBundle.java:390)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.resumeBundle(Framework.java:1176)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:559)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:544)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.incFWSL(StartLevelManager.java:457)
... 5 more
```

[2014-03-11 21:42:58,375] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.internal.Activator} -  Cannot start User Manager Core bundle
org.wso2.carbon.user.core.UserStoreException: Cannot initialize the realm.
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealmService.initializeRealm(DefaultRealmService.java:231)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealmService.(DefaultRealmService.java:101)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealmService.(DefaultRealmService.java:114)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.internal.Activator.startDeploy(Activator.java:70)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.internal.BundleCheckActivator.start(BundleCheckActivator.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl$1.run(BundleContextImpl.java:711)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:702)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:381)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.resume(AbstractBundle.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.resumeBundle(Framework.java:1176)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:559)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:545)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.incFWSL(StartLevelManager.java:458)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.doSetStartLevel(StartLevelManager.java:243)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:438)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)
Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.user.core.UserStoreException: Database Error - ORA-00904: "UM_MAPPED_ATTRIBUTE_DOMAIN": invalid identifier

```
at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.claim.dao.ClaimDAO.addClaimMapping(ClaimDAO.java:261)
at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.claim.dao.ClaimDAO.addCliamMappings(ClaimDAO.java:140)
at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm.populateProfileAndClaimMaps(DefaultRealm.java:420)
at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm.init(DefaultRealm.java:103)
at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealmService.initializeRealm(DefaultRealmService.java:223)
at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealmService.<init>(DefaultRealmService.java:101)
at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealmService.<init>(DefaultRealmService.java:115)
at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.internal.Activator.startDeploy(Activator.java:71)
... 15 more
```

Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00904: "UM_MAPPED_ATTRIBUTE_DOMAIN": invalid identifier

```
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:447)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:396)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:951)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:513)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:227)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:531)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:208)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForRows(T4CPreparedStatement.java:1046)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1336)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3613)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeUpdate(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3694)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.executeUpdate(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1354)
at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.claim.dao.ClaimDAO.addClaimMapping(ClaimDAO.java:227)
at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.claim.dao.ClaimDAO.addCliamMappings(ClaimDAO.java:140)
at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm.populateProfileAndClaimMaps(DefaultRealm.java:420)
at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm.init(DefaultRealm.java:101)
at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealmService.initializeRealm(DefaultRealmService.java:223)
at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealmService.<init>(DefaultRealmService.java:101)
at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealmService.<init>(DefaultRealmService.java:114)
at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.internal.Activator.startDeploy(Activator.java:70)
at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.internal.BundleCheckActivator.start(BundleCheckActivator.java:61)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl$1.run(BundleContextImpl.java:711)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:702)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:683)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:381)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.resume(AbstractBundle.java:390)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.resumeBundle(Framework.java:1176)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:559)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:544)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.incFWSL(StartLevelManager.java:457)
... 5 more
```

[2014-03-11 21:43:12,809]  INFO {org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule} -  TLD skipped. URI: http://tiles.apache.org/tags-tiles is already defined

Are we missing some step?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, WSO2 product is not shipped with updated `oracle_rac.sql` script file in that  version that you have mentioned (basically versions after Carbon 4.2.0). There are database schema changes with 4.2.0..  But these changes have not been incorporated with `oracle_rac.sql`. Therefore you can not use it. But `oracle.sql` file is working fine... So if you just compare the `oracle.sql`  and `oracle_rac.sql` files.  You could edit `oracle_rac.sql` file and get it works. I suggest 1st get the  `oracle.sql` file and update it to support for `oracle_rac`.

Then highlighted different that i have seen

in `oracle.sql`  file you can find following

> START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1 NOCACHE

in `oracle_rac.sql` you can change it as following

> START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1 CACHE 20 ORDER

Hope this would help you.

Comment: I assume you mean to say update oracle.sql for following line START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1 NOCACHE and change it to START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1 CACHE 20 ORDER? Because as you said oracle_rac.sql is old file and does not have all columns/tables needed for 4.6